# How can I publish a Post method on WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed the API Manager and am currently working on registering the API. However, I can easily add the get method in the UI, but the post method is not easy to handle in the UI. Do you have a document or method that explains how to register in an easier way?

I am looking forward to your reply..

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT3AP.png

Comment: What is the APIM version? What is the exact issue/error you are facing?

Comment: @SarankiMagenthirarajah,  no issue..just i want to know how to register the api using post method?  api manager version 4.0.0

Comment: You can create an OpenAPI definition and import the API - https://swagger.io/specification/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the API Publisher UI under the resources configuration . You select the parameter type "Body and set the parameter name "application/json" and select the data type "Object" then click add and don't forget to save the configuration.